# Is it possible to use Salt http.query with ssl client verification?

Tags: ssl, salt-stack

Is it possible to use  Salt `http.query` with ssl client verification?

There are `ca_bundle` and `cert` options for `salt.utils.http.query` command but there is not any `key` options for private key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. `cert` needs to be better documented.

if you look at https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/master/salt/utils/http.py#L339-L351 you can see that `cert` is being checked if it is a list. This is because cert is passed to the underlying http library. and they take cert as a list when it is meant to be used for client side verification. item 0 in the list being the cert item 1 being the key.

really it should be a tuple but a list will work.